# How can I remove unwanted 1px space under navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a horizontal navigation bar in the header of my website. I'm almost done styling it, but I can't work around 1 problem.

**I have, I think about 1px, spacing below the menu. (see the small green line right under 'a blog page'. I discovered it is caused by the float:left that I use on the li-items. If I remove the float, I get an unwanted spacing on the right side of every menu item**

[image: Screenshot]
There's no padding or margin around it and I don't see any other code that could, in my opinion, cause the problem.

HTML (shortened):

```
<nav id="main-nav" role="navigation" aria-label="Hoofdmenu">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" role="menubar" style="">
        <li id="menu-item-2129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-703 current_page_item current_page_parent menu-item-2129"><a href="http://theme.test/blog/">a Blog page</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2100" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-2100" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><a>Template 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2126" class="menu-item menu-item-has-children menu-item-2126" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><a>Template 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#main-nav {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}

#primary-menu {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    line-height: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    list-style: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: With `a {  padding: 0 20px;  display: inline-block;vertical-align:top}`

Comment: do you want to remove the space between nav and category section?

Comment: It would be helpful if you have posted a snippet of your `nav` and the content under `navbar`. It would be difficult to tell without seeing your code

Comment: @Thessa Can you please Share more code? Especially the bottom section of your nav.

Comment: Could it be that you need to give li padding: 0 and margin:0 ? https://css-tricks.com/keep-margins-out-of-link-lists/

Comment: try to `border:0;` for `#main-nav` and `.menu`

Comment: I tried the all the answers here, but none helped. When I inspect the elements, I see my nav-element has a height of 52.05px, my ul has height 0 and my li-items have a line-height of 50px. It seems like the problem would be with the nav- or ul-element.

Answer (score 0):

Do try

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

at the top of your css. As hans-kong posted to eliminate any default browser stylesheets

Comment: This doesn't change anything in the navigation in my case, but thanks for the option!